# Can't Update BIOS (Update file prints 'Test.' and exits)

Tags: bios, battery, freedos, xps

I am trying to run a BIOS update using /forceit command to solve warning: "Battery can't be identified". I have done the following steps:

- Made a Bootable FreeDOS USB Drive using Rufus Portable.
- Copied the BIOS EXE file.
- Restarted the computer and press <kbd>F12</kbd> at boot logo.
- Boot the USB Drive.
- In the DOS window, typed the full name of the file followed by /Forceit

It simply displays "Test." and nothing happens

Example:

`C:\QBL_A18W.EXE /forceit`

Test.

Please help me

Comment: Make and model of PC?

Comment: Dell XPS 15 L521X. Thanks in advance

Comment: "warning: "Battery can't be identified" is it a dell battery?, give us some history on this issue please.